# Heat equation on a thin spherical dome

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Given a hemispherical dome of radius R, assuming negligible the thickness of the dome I'm stuck on the following heat equation problem:
$$T(\theta,t)_{t}=k\Delta T(\theta,t)$$
with the following conditions:
$$T(\theta\le\theta_0,t)=T_1, t\gt0$$
$$T(\theta,0)=T_0$$
Obviously the laplacian operator must be expressed in spherical coordinates. Solving the PDE with Maple, I find a solution with Legendre functions. My problem is: how to take into account the boundary and initial conditions with these functions? Thanks.

Comment: Could you also tell us a bit more about the [context](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1553656) in which this question arose?

Comment: @Lucian: the heating of a dome of a missile in a supersonic flight